# How to configure forward auth in Traefik 2?

Tags: traefik, traefik-authentication

I'm migrating an old API to Traefik 2 and I can't get forward auth to work. The configuration below is pretty much the equivalent of what we had with Traefik 1.7, but I keep getting "404 page not found" for everything unless I comment out the entry point middleware as well as the `auth` labels. The [Traefik documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/) doesn't seem to explain this in any more detail besides adding the middleware itself and some configuration options.

As I understand it this should do forward auth for the web and websecure entry points to the auth entry point and I assigned the `/auth` path on the `auth` entry point to our API container.

```ini
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http]
      middlewares = ["auth"]
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.websecure.http]
      middlewares = ["auth"]
    [entryPoints.websecure.http.tls]
  [entryPoints.auth]
    address = ":7000"

[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.auth.forwardAuth]
    address = "http://127.0.0.1:7000/auth"
```

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:2.8
    volumes:
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 7000:7000
  api:
    image: api
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure
        - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`api.example.org`)
        - traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
        - traefik.http.routers.auth.entrypoints=auth
        - traefik.http.routers.auth.rule=PathPrefix(`/auth`)
        - traefik.http.services.auth.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
```

Comment: what do you see in the logs ? what is the request which is reaching to traefik. I recommend enabling debug mode and check the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why I forgot checking this. The error message was "Could not define the service name for the router: too many services".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my configuration had 2 issues.

1. Middleware must be defined using the [dynamic configurtation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/getting-started/configuration-overview/#the-dynamic-configuration) (note the change to `auth@file`):

```ini
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.web.http]
      middlewares = ["auth@file"]
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.websecure.http]
      middlewares = ["auth@file"]
    [entryPoints.websecure.http.tls]
  [entryPoints.auth]
    address = ":7000"

[providers.file]
  filename = "/etc/traefik/dynamic.toml"
```

```ini
[http.middlewares]
  [http.middlewares.auth.forwardAuth]
    address = "http://127.0.0.1:7000/auth"
```

2. Multiple router definitions require explicit [service targets](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#service):

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    image: api
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure
        - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`api.example.org`)
        - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api # Required
        - traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
        - traefik.http.routers.auth.entrypoints=auth
        - traefik.http.routers.auth.rule=PathPrefix(`/auth`)
        - traefik.http.routers.auth.service=auth # Required
        - traefik.http.services.auth.loadbalancer.server.port=8000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the traefik 2.x ForwardAuth middleware https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/forwardauth/.